# BadValueError: Unsupported type for property <type 'datetime.date'>

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am querying a datastore kind with filter on the string property having date value. The Kind property actual_reported_date i am trying to access is not explicitly defined but a dynamic attribute of type String. it was a mistake of storing the property value in string type instead of date type. Now is there a way we can filter the data set with date comparsion in string format ? Goal is to filter records with actual_reported_date property value greater than input  ( from_date_formatted )

```
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Code which throws exception

```
from_date_formatted = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m- 
                        %d').date()
query = EarningsSurprise.query(EarningsSurprise.ticker == ticker)
query = 
     query.filter(ndb.GenericProperty('actual_reported_date') >= 
                  from_date_formatted)
result = list(query.fetch()) # ( Exception is thrown at this point)
```

Entity

```
class EarningsSurprise(ndb.Expando):
  stock_code = ndb.StringProperty()
  ticker = ndb.StringProperty()
  original_data_source = ndb.StringProperty()
  actual_data_provider = ndb.StringProperty()

  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

  @classmethod
  def create(cls, **kv):
    return EarningsSurprise(**kv)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put a `date()` on the `strptime`.  It does that already:

```
from_date_formatted = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Next, where is `actual_reported_date` defined?  If you have a date in string format, you can easily sort by YYYYMMDDHHMMSS...  So, you can test inequality (as strings!) by:

```
from_date >= actual_reported_date # e.g. ('2018-05-22' >= '2017-11-22')
```